# Intel SSD with retired blocks - how much life left?

Tags: ssd, storage

It's a 4 year old Intel x25 SSD. In the program HD Tune it shows this

```
ID                                    Current  Worst    ThresholdData        Status           
(05) Retired Block Count              100      100      0        21          attention
```

Should the drive still be used and if so, how much longer until it dies? Will I still be able to access my data if that "Data" value reaches 100?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what tool did you use to get this information?

Comment: it's this one: http://www.hdtune.com/

Comment: Doh! Sorry. I missed that.

Comment: It should be good for another 4 years at least if not far longer. SSDs take way longer to fail than optical drives.